# how the best way to make something to center

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to center layout using many ways, but still not find the best way how to do it. in my code below, the button `rental` not be in center. i think it because the margin-left but i'm not find anything. i'm always have a problem to make something to center. please help how the best way to do it. and can i make a margin between class="val" ?

this is my example code

```css
a.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #008CBA;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*width: 20%;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 10PX;*/
}
li{
  float: left;
}
li button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

 #pencetan{
   display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="pencetan">
<ul>
<li><button id="less">-</button></li>
<li><div id="val">1</div></li>
<li><button id="add">+</button></li>
<ul>
<a href="/details " class="button">Rental</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox, pretty good support for all browsers.

Avoid the use of static displays such as table.

```css
a.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #008CBA;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*width: 20%;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 10PX;*/
}
li button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

 #pencetan{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="pencetan">
<ul>
<li><button id="less">-</button></li>
<li><div id="val">1</div></li>
<li><button id="add">+</button></li>
</ul>
<a href="/details " class="button">Rental</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is centring the content because you have `margin: 0 auto` on your `#pencetan`, so this `margin: 0 auto` translates to the following:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
```

About your questions, it really depends on what you want to center.

> To align text, you can use CSS text-align Property, see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

The text-align property specifies the horizontal alignment of text in an element

```
div.a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

> To align containers there is different approaches you can use, I would
>   recommend you to have a look on `CSS flexbox`, see
>   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

you can easily align things like:

```
.container {
  justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly;
}
```

or even it items:

```
.container {
  align-items: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch;
}
```

```css
a.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #008CBA;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*width: 20%;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 10PX;*/
}
li{
  float: left;
}
li button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

 #pencetan{
   display: table;
  margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="pencetan">
<ul>
<li><button id="less">-</button></li>
<li><div id="val">1</div></li>
<li><button id="add">+</button></li>
<ul>
<a href="/details " class="button">Rental</a>
</div>
```